# InputStream will not reset to beginning

Tags: java, parsing, inputstream

```
InputStream data = realResponse.getEntity().getContent();
byte[] preview = new byte[100];
data.read(preview, 0, 100);
```

// Now I want to refer to the InputStream later on, but I want it from the beginning of the stream, not 100 bytes in.  I tried `mark()` it at 100, and then `reset()` after I read the first 100 bytes, but that doesn't work either.

Any ideas?  Probably a stupid mistake..just not seeing it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When you use `mark()` of the [java.io.InputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) object you should check with the `markSupported()` method if your InputStream actually support using mark. According to the API the `InputStream` class doesn't, but the [java.io.BufferedInputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html) class does. Maybe you should embed your stream inside a `BufferedInputStream` object like:

```
InputStream data = new BufferedInputStream(realResponse.getEntity().getContent());
// data.markSupported() should return "true" now
data.mark(some_size);
// work with "data" now
...
data.reset();
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#reset "the reset() method in InputStream does nothing other than throw IOException()" ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If the `InputStream` supports mark (you can check with the `markSupported()` method), then the following should work:

```
InputStream data = realResponse.getEntity().getContent();
byte[] preview = new byte[100];
data.mark(100);
data.read(preview, 0, 100);
data.reset();
```

However, be aware that `data.read(preview, 0, 100)` is *not* guaranteed to read 100 bytes in one go, it may read less.

Comment: I cannot answer this without knowing what the `realResponse` class is (and which version of the library it is in).